# how to convert value of dictionary to list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have dictionary, and I want to convert the value of dictionary to list. this is my dictionary. any help will be appreciated.

```py
data = {
        'form-0-cell': '13a', 'form-0-jam': '07-08', 'form-0-model': 'ADIDAS SUPERSTAR', 'form-0-output': '',
        'form-0-output_jam': '', 'form-0-time': '', 'form-0-output_ot': '', 'form-0-time_ot': '',
        'form-0-time_ot1': '', 'form-0-time_ot2': '',
        'form-1-cell': '13a', 'form-1-jam': '07-08', 'form-1-model': 'ADIDAS SUPERSTAR', 'form-1-output': '20',
        'form-1-output_jam': '', 'form-1-time': '', 'form-1-output_ot': '', 'form-1-time_ot': '',
        'form-1-time_ot1': '', 'form-1-time_ot2': '',
        'form-2-cell': '13c', 'form-2-jam': '07-08', 'form-2-model': 'ADIDAS SUPERSTAR', 'form-2-output': '40',
        'form-2-output_jam': '', 'form-2-time': '', 'form-2-output_ot': '', 'form-2-time_ot': '',
        'form-2-time_ot1': '', 'form-2-time_ot2': '',
        'form-3-cell': '13b', 'form-3-jam': '08-09', 'form-3-model': 'ADIDAS SUPERSTAR', 'form-3-output': '30',
        'form-3-output_jam': '', 'form-3-time': '', 'form-3-output_ot': '', 'form-3-time_ot': '',
        'form-3-time_ot1': '', 'form-3-time_ot2': '',
        'form-4-cell': '13d', 'form-4-jam': '16-17', 'form-4-model': 'ADIDAS SUPERSTAR', 'form-4-output': '40',
        'form-4-output_jam': '', 'form-4-time': '', 'form-4-output_ot': '', 'form-4-time_ot': '',
        'form-4-time_ot1': '', 'form-4-time_ot2': '',
        'form-5-cell': '13d', 'form-5-jam': '16-17', 'form-5-model': ['ADIDAS SUPERSTAR'], 'form-5-output': '40',
        'form-5-output_jam': '', 'form-5-time': '', 'form-5-output_ot': '', 'form-5-time_ot': '',
        'form-5-time_ot1': '', 'form-5-time_ot2': '',
        'form-6-cell': '13d', 'form-6-jam': '17-18', 'form-6-model': ['ADIDAS SUPERSTAR'], 'form-6-output': '10',
        'form-6-output_jam': '', 'form-6-time': '', 'form-6-output_ot': '', 'form-6-time_ot': '',
        'form-6-time_ot1': '', 'form-6-time_ot2': '',
        'form-7-cell': '13d', 'form-7-jam': '18-19', 'form-7-model': ['ADIDAS SUPERSTAR'], 'form-7-output': '60',
        'form-7-output_jam': '', 'form-7-time': '', 'form-7-output_ot': '', 'form-7-time_ot': '',
        'form-7-time_ot1': '', 'form-7-time_ot2': '',
    }
```

This result that I want

```py
#after
 data = {
        'form-0-cell': ['13a'], 'form-0-jam': ['07-08'], 'form-0-model': ['ADIDAS SUPERSTAR'], 'form-0-output': ['10'], 'form-0-output_jam': [''], 'form-0-time': [''], 'form-0-output_ot': [''],   'form-0-time_ot': [''], 'form-0-time_ot1': [''], 'form-0-time_ot2': [''],
        'form-1-cell': ['13a'], 'form-1-jam': ['07-08'], 'form-1-model': ['ADIDAS SUPERSTAR'], 'form-1-output': ['20'], 'form-1-output_jam': [''], 'form-1-time': [''], 'form-1-output_ot': [''],   'form-1-time_ot': [''], 'form-1-time_ot1': [''], 'form-1-time_ot2': [''],
        'form-2-cell': ['13c'], 'form-2-jam': ['07-08'], 'form-2-model': ['ADIDAS SUPERSTAR'], 'form-2-output': ['40'], 'form-2-output_jam': [''], 'form-2-time': [''], 'form-2-output_ot': [''],   'form-2-time_ot': [''], 'form-2-time_ot1': [''], 'form-2-time_ot2': [''],
        'form-3-cell': ['13b'], 'form-3-jam': ['08-09'], 'form-3-model': ['ADIDAS SUPERSTAR'], 'form-3-output': ['30'], 'form-3-output_jam': [''], 'form-3-time': [''], 'form-3-output_ot': [''],   'form-3-time_ot': [''], 'form-3-time_ot1': [''], 'form-3-time_ot2': [''],
        'form-4-cell': ['13d'], 'form-4-jam': ['16-17'], 'form-4-model': ['ADIDAS SUPERSTAR'], 'form-4-output': ['40'], 'form-4-output_jam': [''], 'form-4-time': [''], 'form-4-output_ot': [''],   'form-4-time_ot': [''], 'form-4-time_ot1': [''], 'form-4-time_ot2': [''],
        'form-5-cell': ['13d'], 'form-5-jam': ['16-17'], 'form-5-model': ['ADIDAS SUPERSTAR'], 'form-5-output': ['40'], 'form-5-output_jam': [''], 'form-5-time': [''], 'form-5-output_ot': [''],   'form-5-time_ot': [''], 'form-5-time_ot1': [''], 'form-5-time_ot2': [''],
        'form-6-cell': ['13d'], 'form-6-jam': ['17-18'], 'form-6-model': ['ADIDAS SUPERSTAR'], 'form-6-output': ['10'], 'form-6-output_jam': [''], 'form-6-time': [''], 'form-6-output_ot': [''],   'form-6-time_ot': [''], 'form-6-time_ot1': [''], 'form-6-time_ot2': [''],
        'form-7-cell': ['13d'], 'form-7-jam': ['18-19'], 'form-7-model': ['ADIDAS SUPERSTAR'], 'form-7-output': ['60'], 'form-7-output_jam': [''], 'form-7-time': [''], 'form-7-output_ot': [''],   'form-7-time_ot': [''], 'form-7-time_ot1': [''], 'form-7-time_ot2': [''],
    }
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow! Have a look on [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) and what is a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will even have rewards at visiting those pages. We will not write code for you. Share what you have tried so far and we will try to improve it.

Comment: `data = {key: [value] if not isinstance(value, list) else value for key, value in data.items()}`

Answer (score 0):

Use this for loop:

```
for val in data:
    data[val]=[data[val]]
```

`val` here is the key for the dictionary.

Comment: It'll create unnecessary nested lists.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```py
for key, value in data.items():
    if isinstance(value, list): # Keep value if already a list
        data[key] = value
    else:
        data[key] = [value]
```

It will list the value if not already a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dict comprehension.

To check if value is already a list you can use next methods:

- Get type of values using [`type(value)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) and compare it with `list`;
- Use [`isinstance(value, list)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) which do all comparisons by itself.

Code:

```
data_ = {key: [value] if type(value) is not list else value for key, value in data.items()}
```

or:

```
data_ = {key: [value] if not isinstance(value, list) else value for key, value in data.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'form-0-cell': ['13a'], 'form-0-jam': ['07-08'], 'form-0-model': ['ADIDAS SUPERSTAR'], 'form-0-output': [''], 'form-0-output_jam': [''], 'form-0-time': [''], 'form-0-output_ot': [''], 'form-0-time_ot': [''], 'form-0-time_ot1': [''], 'form-0-time_ot2': [''], 'form-1-cell': ['13a'], 'form-1-jam': ['07-08'], 'form-1-model': ['ADIDAS SUPERSTAR'], 'form-1-output': ['20'], 'form-1-output_jam': [''], 'form-1-time': [''], 'form-1-output_ot': [''], 'form-1-time_ot': [''], 'form-1-time_ot1': [''], 'form-1-time_ot2': [''], 'form-2-cell': ['13c'], 'form-2-jam': ['07-08'], 'form-2-model': ['ADIDAS SUPERSTAR'], 'form-2-output': ['40'], 'form-2-output_jam': [''], 'form-2-time': [''], 'form-2-output_ot': [''], 'form-2-time_ot': [''], 'form-2-time_ot1': [''], 'form-2-time_ot2': [''], 'form-3-cell': ['13b'], 'form-3-jam': ['08-09'], 'form-3-model': ['ADIDAS SUPERSTAR'], 'form-3-output': ['30'], 'form-3-output_jam': [''], 'form-3-time': [''], 'form-3-output_ot': [''], 'form-3-time_ot': [''], 'form-3-time_ot1': [''], 'form-3-time_ot2': [''], 'form-4-cell': ['13d'], 'form-4-jam': ['16-17'], 'form-4-model': ['ADIDAS SUPERSTAR'], 'form-4-output': ['40'], 'form-4-output_jam': [''], 'form-4-time': [''], 'form-4-output_ot': [''], 'form-4-time_ot': [''], 'form-4-time_ot1': [''], 'form-4-time_ot2': [''], 'form-5-cell': ['13d'], 'form-5-jam': ['16-17'], 'form-5-model': ['ADIDAS SUPERSTAR'], 'form-5-output': ['40'], 'form-5-output_jam': [''], 'form-5-time': [''], 'form-5-output_ot': [''], 'form-5-time_ot': [''], 'form-5-time_ot1': [''], 'form-5-time_ot2': [''], 'form-6-cell': ['13d'], 'form-6-jam': ['17-18'], 'form-6-model': ['ADIDAS SUPERSTAR'], 'form-6-output': ['10'], 'form-6-output_jam': [''], 'form-6-time': [''], 'form-6-output_ot': [''], 'form-6-time_ot': [''], 'form-6-time_ot1': [''], 'form-6-time_ot2': [''], 'form-7-cell': ['13d'], 'form-7-jam': ['18-19'], 'form-7-model': ['ADIDAS SUPERSTAR'], 'form-7-output': ['60'], 'form-7-output_jam': [''], 'form-7-time': [''], 'form-7-output_ot': [''], 'form-7-time_ot': [''], 'form-7-time_ot1': [''], 'form-7-time_ot2': ['']}
```

Comment: It will create unnecessary nested lists.

Comment: But ... you've copied my comment.

Comment: Sorry I din't notice your comment

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do is:

```
value=[i for i in data.values()]
keys=[i for i in data.keys()]
d={}
for i in range(len(data)):
    d.update({keys[i]:[value[i]]})

d
```